# How to validate a Facebook application existence?

Tags: facebook, api

I'm currently building a Facebook integration program, and I wanted to know if it is possible to verify the existence of Facebook application by either with or without the Facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the Facebook graph api by accessing the app's name or id:
http://graph.facebook.com/appId
or http://graph.facebook.com/appName

If you are trying to search for apps, you could scrape this url:
https://www.facebook.com/search.php?q=appNameSearch&type=apps